# SQLite return records where date is more than a week old

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am making a program for a book library and in the sqlite database there is a table for the books which includes the date that book was last taken out.

I need a query to show overdue books. My code so far follows:

```
def findOverdueBooks(event):
    findRecords = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE takenOut < 'now' ,  '-1 week' " )
    for row in findRecords:
        print(row)
```

I am getting this error when the code is run

```
line 31, in findOverdueBooks
findRecords = c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookList WHERE takenOut < 'now' ,  '-1 week' " )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

I don't understand why the comma is causing an error as that is how it is shown in the [documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/date.php).

Comment: missing the call to the date function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your datetime comparison is causing the issue here. It rather should be

```
AND takenOut < datetime('now', '-7 day')
```

See [SQLite Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more information

That should be a `>` comparison

```
AND takenOut > datetime('now', '-7 day')
```

You can as well try like below, if you are comparing with the date part only

```
WHERE DATE(takenOut) >= DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got rid of the syntax error. However, it isn't returning any results. It should as in my database i have records where the takenOut field is "2016-11-15". Any idea why? If not then no problem, I can just make a new question

Comment: I changed it to say '-7 day' instead of '-1 week' and now it works, it's weird how that caused the problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: what does the `weekday 0` do?