# Write an SQLite query that returns all records with dates older than a certain value

Tags: sqlite, date-comparison

I have a table with 5 columns, one of which is LastVisit (the date of the last visit to a restaurant). I want to write a query that will return all the restaurants that are liked but have not been visited for more than three months, but I am making some kind of mistake with the date functions (I think).

If I make my database and insert these values:

```
CREATE TABLE MyRestaurants(Name VARCHAR, Cuisine VARCHAR, Distance INTEGER, LastVisit VARCHAR, Enjoy INTEGER);

INSERT INTO MyRestaurants (Name, Cuisine, Distance, LastVisit, Enjoy) 
VALUES ('Dakshin', 'Indian', 5, 2019-01-13, 1);

INSERT INTO MyRestaurants (Name, Cuisine, Distance, LastVisit, Enjoy) 
VALUES ('Cactus', 'Mexican', 6, 2018-01-4, 1);
```

Then I make this query:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM MyRestaurants 
WHERE Enjoy = 1 AND DATE(LastVisit) <= DATE('now', '-3 month') 
ORDER BY Name;
```

I expect it to return Cactus, but it returns both Cactus and Dakshin.

I found this thread: [SQLite return records where date is more than a week old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887425/sqlite-return-records-where-date-is-more-than-a-week-old)

But when I try >= it returns no values, when I try just LastVisit instead of DATE(LastVisit) it returns no values, and when I try 90 days instead of 3 months it returns no values. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insert statements seem to have a problem, because the date literals are just string literals, and so should be wrapped in single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO MyRestaurants (Name, Cuisine, Distance, LastVisit, Enjoy)
VALUES ('Dakshin', 'Indian', 5, '2019-01-13', 1);

INSERT INTO MyRestaurants (Name, Cuisine, Distance, LastVisit, Enjoy)
VALUES ('Cactus', 'Mexican', 6, '2018-01-04', 1);
```

Then, if you want records which did not occurr in the last 3 months you should use:

```
SELECT Name
FROM MyRestaurants
WHERE Enjoy = 1 AND LastVisit <= DATE('now', '-3 month')
ORDER BY Name;
```

Note that there is no formal date type in SQLite.  Rather, dates are just stored as `TEXT`.  You correctly used an ISO format for your date literals, which were correct, other than possibly that you didn't escape them in single quotes.

Comment: Thank you! I actually want the restaurants that haven't been visited lately, so the inequality was right, but I definitely was not putting the strings into the table correctly. This solved my problem completely.